# OPENXML SDK VS Microsoft Platform Interop Assemblies

Tags: ms-office, openxml, office-pia

I have a requirement where in I need to scan Office documents and remove any metadata found embedded in the file/document.  I am new to developing applications on Microsoft Office and found that I could either use the Platform Interop Assemblies or the OPENXML SDK to work with Office docs (word, excel and powerpoint).

However, I couldnt find any source/link which explains the difference between PIA and OPENXML.  Could anyone please explain as to when which option needs to be looked at and which one is easy to work with (ie., less effort on learning curve)?

Answer (score 1):

The huge problem with PIA is you will be dealing with COM interops unmanaged environment.
Here are the [differences](http://sharepoint2010master.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/advantages-of-openxml-over-interop-for.html)